# Why is gmp.so not copied to the right location when compiling PHP to use it as a shared library?

Tags: php, ubuntu, compilation, gmp

I recently recompiled PHP CLI to use the GMP extension as a shared library and installed it using `dpkg -i` I was using the source provided by the Ubuntu package of PHP5 (`apt-get source php5`). Afterwards PHP was not able to find the gmp.so file. After performing a `find` on my system for this file, I found that it was located in the php5-5.3.2/cli-build/modules/gmp.so directory (in the tree where I had the original PHP source). I was surprised that the package installer didn't copy this library over to the specified install directory (it does this for all the other PHP extensions). Is this a bug, or am I missing some part of the compilation/installation process?

Here is my configure command:

```
'../configure'  '--build=i486-linux-gnu' '--host=i486-linux-gnu' '--disable-all' \
     '--prefix=/usr' '--with-config-file-path=/etc/php5/clibare' \ 
     '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php5/clibare/conf.d' '--with-mysql=shared,/usr/lib' \ 
     '--with-curl=shared,/usr' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-posix' '--enable-json' \
     '--with-gmp=shared,/usr' '--with-system-tzdata'
```